# from_base64() not decoding back to original text

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

The from_base64() does not decode correctly. Please see the problem demo below.

```
mysql> select to_base64('sometext');

+-----------------------+
| to_base64('sometext') |
+-----------------------+
| c29tZXRleHQ=          |
+-----------------------+
1 row in set (0.27 sec)

mysql> select from_base64('c29tZXRleHQ=');
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| from_base64('c29tZXRleHQ=')                              |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| 0x736F6D6574657874                                       |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

This was working till i moved to latest ubuntu 19.10.
Server version: 8.0.19 MySQL Community Server - GPL

mysql --version
mysql  Ver 8.0.19-0ubuntu0.19.10.3 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the following.

```
--binary-as-hex

When this option is given, mysql displays binary data using hexadecimal notation (0xvalue). This occurs whether the overall output dislay format is tabular, vertical, HTML, or XML.

As of MySQL 8.0.19, when mysql operates in interactive mode, this option is enabled by default. In addition, output from the status (or \s) command includes this line when the option is enabled implicitly or explicitly:

To disable hexadecimal notation, use --skip-binary-as-hex
```

[MySQL client options](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-command-options.html)